# Issue with a Bash loop that uses an integer

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

So I looked up the examples of a while loop and put the script together as so and still am having issues. If I was to guess I would say it with the arithmetic part of the bc function.

I want the loop to run until I hit a thousand and then count how many times it ran. I am not to the counting part of the script yet as I am still just trying to get it to run (yes I know awk would be easier).

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=120 #this will be a variable that is read in from a menu but 120 is ok for now
while [ $total -lt 1000000 ]
do
echo $total
total=$(bc<<<"scale=2;$total +  $total * .1") #I don't know if I have to use "let" before total but it did not make a difference.
done.
```

I am getting an error with the line that starts with "total" but the structure of the command seems to fit all the examples I could find. What gives?

Comment: There are two lines that start with "total", but I would expect you to get an error on line 3, that starts with `While`, and I would expect the error to be `While: command not found` (the keyword "while" is not capitalized).  Once that's fixed, I would expect errors about "1,000,000" not being an integer.

Comment: If I run this at the prompt it works fine but in a loop...not so much         total=120
    total=$(bc<<<"scale=2;$total +  $total * .1");echo $total  --and then the output is 132.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bc` for the comparison, too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

total=120
while [ "$(bc <<< "$total < 1000000")" == 1 ]
do
    echo $total
    total=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$total +  $total * .1")
done
```

Comment: THANKS SOO MUCH! I look forward to be the guy helping out in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are dealing with integers, you can write your loop with the arithmetic expression `(( ... ))`, without the need for an external command like `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=120
while ((total < 1000000)); do
  echo $total
  ((total = total + total / 10))
done
```